# orangehrm error after moving to a new domain

Tags: php, open-source, filepath

I just moved my orangehrm from a free hosting solution to a paid one. I have updated the mysql credentials and set the chmod permissions. However, when I visit the start page I get the following error:

> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/home/donut/public_html/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/utility/KeyHandler.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5') in
>   /homepages/1/d316893459/htdocs/bcsdhrm/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php
>   on line 188

I am noob to orangehrm, so please help me with this !!!  I have no idea what to do from here.

Thank You

Comment: Make sure your file is uploaded correctly on the new server.

Comment: ya its totally uploaded correctly, looks like a include_path error 
but i don't know where to change this, I am not able to grab in which file i have to set what include path !?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete your OrangeHRM Configuration Cache File.

Just access '/var/www/orangehrm/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/' and delete the file 'config_autoload.yml.php'.

Ps: Make a backup first... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I am noob to orangehrm

It's impossible to say without access to the server, but at a guess, somewhere in the config for the application (orangehtm or symfony) you've set a path /home/donut/public_html/... which has been copied to the new system - but needs to be updated to /homepages/1/d316893459/htdocs/bcsdhrm/...

Assuming that your version of the autoloader class looks somethng like [this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php), then it's the PHP include_path which is the problem. This can be set in the php.ini file, in .htaccess files or overridden in .htaccess files. I'd start by accessing the server over ssh and running:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H '/home/donut' {} \;
```